# Jquery Function not working on my home page but working on other page

Tags: jquery, fadeout, mouseleave

I am trying to hide `dvSubCat` on jQuery Mouse leave function, but it is not working and it is working good on the other page exact same code.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<div id="dvMain" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="dvCat1" style="float: left">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlCategories" Style="background-color: rgba(154, 153, 153, 0.99)"
            ForeColor="White" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCategory" CssClass="hoverStyleForCategories" ForeColor="White" Font-Underline="false"
                        Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'
                        OnClick="btnCategory_Click" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>' />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
    <div id="dvSubCat" style="width: 20%; float: left">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlSubCategory" Style="background-color: orange"
            ForeColor="White" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubCat" OnClick="btnSubCat_Click" ForeColor="White" Font-Underline="false"
                    Text='<%# Eval("SubCategoryName") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SubCategoryId") %>' runat="server" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dvMain").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#dvSubCat").fadeOut()
    });
});
```

jQuery file I am using:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `#dvCat1` is the only element in `#dvMain` and `#dvCat1` is floated (`style="float: left"`), the `#dvMain` elements height is not calculated properly (it's effectively 0) and `mouseleave` event won't fire.

You can:

1) Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#dvMain`

2) Add an element with `clear: both;` style (e.g. `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`) at the very bottom of the `#dvMain`

There are also other tricks to fix this issue. Search for `clearfix` if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but using both techniques still mouse leave event is not firing.i cant understand the same code is working on other page and not working non my main home page :(